# Ruby On Rails - Rendering HTML after view template loads

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-oauth

I posted a simliar question previously, but I thought it would be better to start with a simpler example first to understand how AJAX works.

Basically the application makes an API call to twitter and searches for all tweets which include '@youtube' in the tweet text. The problem is that sometimes the searching can take a while, so instead of waiting for the search to finish then render the view, I would like to render a view template containing an empty div, then fill this div with HTML after the controller method finishes running.

So far, this is what I have:

In **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'

  root to: 'pages#index'
  get 'index' => 'pages#index'
  get 'tweets' => 'pages#tweets'
end
```

In **pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def tweets
    html = ''
    tweets = TweetController.load_tweets(current_user)
    tweets.each {|tweet| html << "<p>#{tweet.text}</p>"}
    render :html => html.html_safe, :layout => false
  end

end
```

In **tweet_controller.rb**

```
class TweetController < ApplicationController

  def self.load_tweets(auth_user)
    tweets = User.twitter.search('to:youtube', result_type: 'recent').collect.sort_by &:created_at
    return !auth_user.nil? ? tweets : [].to_enum
  end

end
```

In **tweets.html.erb**

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
      url: 'tweets',
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
          $('#tweet_view').append(html)
      }
  });
</script>

<div id='tweet_view'></div>
```

So after the user presses a button on the index page, they are sent to the Twitter API authorisation page, then redirected back to `tweets.html.erb`.

However, instead of loading the template first then filling the div with HTML, it seems to still be loading all tweets then rendering the page, but I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways actually you can solve this.

1. Using two actions : Just move everything present in tweets.html.erb to pages/index.html.erb

In **pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end 

  def tweets
    html = ''
    tweets = TweetController.load_tweets(current_user)
    tweets.each {|tweet| html << "<p>#{tweet.text}</p>"}
    render :html => html.html_safe, :layout => false
  end

end
```

In **pages/index.html.erb**

```
   <script>
  $.ajax({
      url: 'tweets',
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
          $('#tweet_view').append(html)
      }
  });
</script>

<div id='tweet_view'></div>
```

In **tweet_controller.rb**

```
class TweetController < ApplicationController

  def self.load_tweets(auth_user)
    tweets = User.twitter.search('to:youtube', result_type: 'recent').collect.sort_by &:created_at
    return !auth_user.nil? ? tweets : [].to_enum
  end

end
```

And make sure when user presses button page should be redirected back to pages#index action from Twitter API authorization page.

**EDIT OR :**

2. Using parameter separator to distinguish API redirect and tweets load requests.

In **pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def tweets
    if(params[:load_tweets] == 'true')
     html = ''
     tweets = TweetController.load_tweets(current_user)
     tweets.each {|tweet| html << "<p>#{tweet.text}</p>"}
     render :html => html.html_safe, :layout => false
    end
  end

end
```

In **pages/tweets.html.erb**

```
   <script>
  $.ajax({
      url: 'tweets?load_tweets=true',
      cache: false,
      success: function (html) {
          $('#tweet_view').append(html)
      }
  });
</script>

<div id='tweet_view'></div>
```

In **tweet_controller.rb**

```
class TweetController < ApplicationController

  def self.load_tweets(auth_user)
    tweets = User.twitter.search('to:youtube', result_type: 'recent').collect.sort_by &:created_at
    return !auth_user.nil? ? tweets : [].to_enum
  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you, but why would I have to move everything to `index.html.erb` if I want the button on the index page to send the user to the tweets page at `pages/tweets.html.erb`? I currently have it to redirect back to the `pages#tweets` page.